# When does an ISingletonDependency implementation get instantiated by Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I need to implement a singleton in an Orchard module. On reading about ISingletonDependency I thought that must be the answer but my type is never instantiated.

This is the code I am using for testing. Implemented in a single file at the root level of my module project.

```
using Orchard;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SingletonTestModule
{
    public interface IMySingleton : ISingletonDependency
    {
    }

    public class MySingleton : IMySingleton
    {
        public MySingleton()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What else do I need to do to have the orchard shell instantiate my singleton?

Comment: That's it, yes. What happens when you try to inject it? Show the code that you're using to inject it. Also, 99% of people who think they need a singleton are wrong ;)

Comment: Thats probably the problem, I'm not injecting it. I was expecting it to be created as a singleton. Where would I inject it from? I'd be happy to discuss my need for a singleton by email if you think I shouldn't need on in Orchard.

Comment: Moving that to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contract that ISingleton establishes is that there will be only one instance of that class per tenant under a given Orchard instance (note that this is per tenant, not per app domain like with a "static" implementation). When that instance gets created depends on you: the first time you ask for that class to be injected, the instance will get created and injected. Next time you ask for it, you'll get the same instance as the first time.

A quick note on when to use singletons: almost never. There are very very few legitimate use cases for singletons, and these are usually deep into the framework, not in application code (implementing caching APIs and global stores are possible ones). See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for some links to critiques of the pattern: "There is criticism of the use of the singleton pattern, as some consider it an anti-pattern, judging that it is overused, introduces unnecessary restrictions in situations where a sole instance of a class is not actually required, and introduces global state into an application."

Most of the times I've seen people want to use a singleton in Orchard, they could just as well have used a regular IDependency class, together with some caching.

You may have a legitimate use case, but I'm still adding this for other persons finding this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I see how its meant to work now, unfortunately thats not the behaviour I'm seeing. I am injecting the singleton using this code `public class Module : IOrchardShellEvents { public Module(IScheduledTaskManager taskManager, IRepository<ServiceSettingsPartRecord> settingsRepository, IAuditWriter audit, IMySingleton s) ...` When I do I see the ctor for MySingleton called 3 times and injected into the ctor for Module 3 times each time with a different hash code.

Comment: So you probably have 3 shells running (ie. tenants). As Bertrand described - `ISingletonDependency` is created per-shell, not per appdomain. If you want to debug which shell you're currently in - the quickest way is to inject `ShellSettings` and inspect it in ctor.